# Old Access Database can't print reports

Tags: ms-access, printing

An old Access database front end for my Dad's business is giving me problems after he updated to the 2016 version of Access. The front end is managed by some forms and macros and reports that point to a backend file which actually houses the database.

The issue arises when attempting to print reports (see attached screenshot)[image: Print preview ribbon]

The form maintains focus and won't allow for any interaction with the ribbon or the report windows it opens up so the reports can't be properly read inside access (cause the zoom level is too small) nor can they be printed reliably.

The front end was originally programmed in the 2003 access format but migrating the files forward to the newer .accdb format don't seem to help. Is there a flag I can change or macro I can add to allow for focus change from the form?

Comment: Is form set as modal?

Comment: I'm not sure, how can I tell?

Comment: Yep it was, changing this value gave me the desired behavior